# Out of gas exception: error when using GUI/JS but not within truffle

Tags: truffle, out-of-gas

I'm trying something with Ethereum and my current testing environment is Truffle.

In the smart contract I have a struct with 5 fields (bytes32, bytes32, bytes32, address, bool). If a call a function (that has as parameters the first three bytes32) that writes in an array of struct within ***Truffle*** everything works fine (and then I'm also able to read the values, get them by index using a mapping and so on).

Now I've some problem when dealing with AngularJS and the GUI. If I create a page with an input form for writin a bytes32 on a bytes32 variable in the contract everything works. The problems arises when I pass some arguments (1, 2 or 3) and then write inside the array of struct. I got an out of gas expection.

Do you have any insights on way there could be some problems? I'm sure the transaction doesn't consume all gas (and I've tried to increase the limit) because in Truffle console everything works fine.

Thanks for your time

-------- UPDATE

I think that a possible solution could be to set for the single call of the function an higher ***startgas*** than the default one. The limit I've first increased was the BGL.

```
contract.testWrite2(testNumber1, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})
```

This is the code for calling the *testWrite2* function of my *contract* passing one parameter and using the account 0. How can I set the *startgas* for this simple invocation?

```
contract.testWrite2(testNumber1, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], startgas: 200000})
```

This unfortunately doens't seem to work. The strange thing is that from truffle console all the functions are working correctly, while from the GUI they're not.

The code of the controller that's managing the GUI is this

```
    app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
        $scope.pageTest = "Welcome to the Test page";
        $scope.testWr = 'None';

        $scope.testWrite = function(testNumber1) {
        var contract = Authentication.deployed();
        contract.testWrite2(testNumber1, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function() {
          $scope.testWr = 'success';
          $scope.$apply();
      })
   }

 })
```

And this is the html page in which there is an input form for a number:

```
{{pageTest}}</br>

<div class="row">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <form ng-submit="testWrite(test_number1)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="testNumber1">Hardware</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="testNumber1"
                        placeholder="ble:..."
                        ng-model="test_number1">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Test</button>
        </form>
</div>

</br>
Write status: {{testWr}}
```

To test it out, I wanted to call the function and then simply change the variable testWr on the HTML page.

Thanks to everybody that will help me :)

Comment: Share some code. Have you put ether on the accounts you are using?

Comment: @BennyM I've added other explanations and some code :) Sorry for the delay but I've spent time over some documentation before continuing with the implementation!

Comment: 200k isn't really that much gas. Have you tried 2 million? Also, the variable is called `gas`, not `startgas`.  You want `contract.testWrite2(testNumber1, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 2000000})`

Comment: @TjadenHess I've solved the problem! I've used *startgas* because I've seen it somewhere, while with **gas** it's working fine and I need only 160k of gas for the transaction! Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TjadenHess I've found the solution: the variable to use inside the function call is ***gas*** and not startgas.

Now everything is working fine and I need 160k for the transaction to be completed.